# class in function name resulting in a 500 error?

Tags: php, apache, naming-conventions

I've almost lost my mind trying to understand why my local server (apache on Ubuntu) started to give a 500 message.

It turned out that the problem was caused by a function called `classView()`. I renamed it to `classTemplateView()` but still 500. Then I've tried with `stupidView()` (I was getting tired) and it worked again.

I've searched a while but I haven't found anything saying that class inside a function name is "prohibited", is it?

Comment: Please enable `error_reporting` and `display_errors` to see more verbose errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's fine: "class" on its own is a reserved word, but not when it's part of another word.

A quick test script:

```
<?php

function classView()
{
    echo 'test';
}

classView();
```

Echoes 'test' as expected.

Comment: @BenM, OP is talking about a function too

Comment: @BenM Yes. Please re-read the original question: "It turned out that the problem was caused by a function called classView()".